# how to pass multiple values for imagesize in google custom search api

Tags: google-custom-search

I am using google custom search API to show images, now I want to display both xxlarge, huge images in search results.

**Custom search api link:**

> https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key={your Key}&cx={Search
>   Engine
>   Id}&q=hello&searchType=image&alt=json&safe=high&filter=1&num=10&fileType=jpg&
>   **imgSize=huge**&start=1

In the above link for image size currently I can get huge images, I want to include xxlarge images.

Comment: As of 2021, I'm not able to select multiple sizes of images or multiple colors in Google search.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue, there doesn't seem to be a way of specifying multiple image sizes, or indeed or doing larger than a certain size, as you can do with google search tools (i.e. on google.com).

so what I am thinking of doing to work around this is calling 2 searches, and adding both results that I want to an array to combine them.